# File.Delete doesn't delete my prefetch files

Tags: c#

I'm having some issues trying to delete specific .pf files, this is my code

```
foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"%systemroot%\prefetch"))
                System.IO.File.Delete(file);
```

But it didn't work, i put it in a button and when i click it, nothing happens
and im also trying to make it so it can only delete specific file names that are put in the textbox so like "CHROME.EXE-D9999999" It deletes only that file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to ask questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You cannot use %systemroot%, use Environment.GetFolderPath() instead.  64-bit code and UAC elevation required.

Comment: Okay i'll try it

Comment: I fixed it, looked like all i had to do is just put 'C:\windows\prefetch' instead of systemroot